Rewrite fraction of products
I recently saw this kind of rewriting of a fraction I was interested in:
$$\frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{(n+k)\ldots(n+1)}=\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\ldots\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\ldots\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$$
and I've been puzzled on how this transformation is being done.
Since the statement was made in a way that made it seem quite "trivial" I'd assume that this is derived from a rather important theorem, but I cannot remember where to look for it.
Any help would be much appreciated!

You just divide both the numerator and the denominator by $n^k$.

Factor an $n$ out of each term in the product from the numerator and denominator. So for example $n-1=n(1-\frac1n)$ and $n+k=n(1-\frac kn)$. Now pair off the $n$ terms in the numerator and denominator to cancel.

Not my proudest question. Thanks a lot!

To solve the problem and understand the technique:
$$\frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{(n+k)\ldots(n+1)}=\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\ldots\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\ldots\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$$
You could do the following multiply top and bottom by: \begin{equation}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}\end{equation}
This would then lead to the following:
\begin{align}
\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots(n-k+1)}{(n+k)(n+k-1)\ldots(n+1)}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}&=\frac{\frac{n}{n}(\frac{n}{n}-\frac{1}n)\ldots(\frac{n}n-\frac{k+1}n)}{(\frac{n}n+\frac{k}n)\ldots(\frac{n}n+\frac{1}n)}\\&=\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\ldots\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\ldots\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}
\end{align}
Giving you then the final answer as:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\ldots\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\ldots\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}
\end{equation}
For any clarifications please comment.
